# Подскажите CSS-фреймворки и библиотеки с открытым исходным кодом

Tags: css, framework

Посоветуйте Open Source фреймворки и библиотеки CSS, которые позволят сэкономить время на верстке и облегчат работу начинающему разработчику?

Comment: бутстрап , фундэйшен,

Comment: как мне переформулировать? если я хочу узнать какие фреймворки применяют разработчики для быстрой верстки, не с 0, широкоиспользуемые

Comment: @Уважаемые, grundy, подскажите как его можно переформулировать?

Comment: желающим дать ответ: лучше дополнить этим ответом [описание метки css](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/tags/css/info)

Comment: @alexanderbarakin как поправить вопрос , не очень понятно? смысл в том что я хочу знать какие фреймворки используют проф. разработчики

Comment: с учётом вашего хотения — увы, никак. смотрите правила. если что-то неясно — задавайте вопрос на мете.

Answer (score 3):

Попробуй  [bootstrap](http://getbootstrap.com/)

очень удобный

Answer (score 2):

Добавим еще:

1. [Materialize](http://materializecss.com/) — по гайдлайнам материал-дизайна от Google
2. [KickStart](http://www.99lime.com/elements/) — свежий и не сильно большой фреймворк

Comment: @УткаУчитсяУму Да, вы правы. Открытый исходник не делает лицензию свободной

Answer (score 2):

От себя добавлю:

1. [Google Web Starter Kit](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/starter-kit/) — полноценный фреймворк от Google
2. [godlike.css](https://www.kobzarev.com/makeup/godlike-css/) — небольшая библиотека (кстати, я участвовал в ее разработке), которая помогает разработчикам  легче справляться с ежедневными трудностями, с помощью обнуления стандартных стилей, фикса багов браузеров и добавления юзабилити.